# Check if email address already exists if so show message if not then add to table

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I was hoping to get a little insight on this.

What I have is a form collecting firstname, lastname, city, state, and email address. This form is using jquery validation plugin and the form plugin.

I would like to check if email already exists... if so then spit out a message that tells them they already exist.

This is what I have for my update.php script in which the form if using to add names to the mysql database:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("host","username","password");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("table", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO wallnames (ID, firstname, lastname, city, state, email)
 VALUES('NULL','$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[city]','$_POST[state]','$_POST[email]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
 }

 echo "<p style=\width:350px; height:200px; vertical-align:middle;\><strong>Thank you for adding your info</strong></p>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that inserting `'NULL'` as a string is what you want to do? Shouldn't that be `NULL`?

Comment: To be completely honest I am a little fresh with this stuff and saw an example and just plugged it in. It seems to be working with it. If I remove NULL... I get an error

Mark - I am also not very sure I completely understand how to add a unique index

Comment: It should just be NULL without the quotation if you want the value NULL unless you want the word 'null'. If you are using Mysql, there should be a button you click to make a field a unique index. If not, just use what Mark wrote.

Comment: @Matthew: You should also note that what you've done is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Sorry if this sounds like too much work, but I suggest you ditch whatever tutorial/example site you're following and learn instead from a reliable source that teaches good practices. You'll save yourself a lot of time in the long run. See this thread for some ideas of where to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119083/php-tutorial-that-is-security-accuracy-and-maintainability-conscious

Comment: @Mark... thanks for the insight. I will take a look and make sure that this gets done the right way.

Comment: @Mark... Okay have placed a unique index on the email column in my database.

That has helped out a lot... I have an error message displaying if email is a dup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should [create a unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) on the email column, then the insert will fail if you try to insert the same email twice.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_wallnames_email ON wallnames (email)
```

You can also run this query to test if an email already exists:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM wallnames WHERE email = 'test@example.com')
```

It will return either 0 if the email is unused, or 1 if it already exists in the table.